# Achieve multi threading in WASM for making http requests (using reqwest crate)

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, reqwest, rust-wasm

I am trying to convert current implementation to WASM (for cloudflare workers).

But I have been facing problem with current implementation is that it uses multi threading to [make requests](https://github.com/ssddOnTop/tailcall/blob/7f316050523c5c8340f68cd2967c3e4b514d7710/src/http/client.rs#L51), but I am unable to compile that code for WASM, so currently I am using `async_std::spwan_local` to make requests ([source](https://github.com/ssddOnTop/tailcall/blob/7f316050523c5c8340f68cd2967c3e4b514d7710/src/http/client.rs#L49)) which forces the program to execute each request on single thread. Is there anyway that I can achieve multi threading with the same?

Here is a minimal example I made to reproduce the error (further steps are in readme): https://github.com/ssddOnTop/cf_workers

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot achieve multi-threading in WASM as a Cloudflare worker. It is not supported.

The [Cloudflare Worker API documentation on WebAssembly](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/webassembly/) says:

> #### Threading
>
> Threading is not possible in Workers. Each Worker runs in a single thread, and the Web Worker API is not supported.

---

For additional context. WebAssembly does not (yet) natively support threads. The way multi-threading can be done currently is by jumping through the JavaScript [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). As such, Rust code targeting WebAssembly cannot be multi-threaded (i.e. using `std::thread::*` APIs will fail). If this were for a website, the Web Worker API would be a option, but you'd have to navigate that manually. But since Cloudflare does not provide the Web Worker API to its workers, then that option is not available either.

I'm also skeptical that your design had any merit in the first place; a thread-per-request model is not known to be particularly efficient.

Comment: I made mistake in framing the question, it's not thread-per-request model, it is making concurrent requests but I was thinking to add something to make it faster

Comment: @Sandip Having multiple requests in-flight is possible with async, that's what your MRE currently does from the looks of it. But no, you won't be able to use more than one thread for it. Cloudflare workers are built for horizontal scalability (just create more workers to handle more load) rather than vertical scalability (giving workers more resources - RAM, CPU, etc. - to handle more load).